# Javascript Filter an Array to give subset from two Range Parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, range, subset

How do I filter an array two give me the subset created by overlap of two ranges?

For example, suppose Here's my array with a bunch of objects:

```
const list = [{
    id: 1,
    price: "10",
    weight: "19.45"
  },{
    id: 2,
    price: "14",
    weight: "27.8"
  },{
    id: 3,
    price: "45",
    weight: "65.7"
  },{
    id: 4,
    price: "37",
    weight: "120.5"
  },{
    id: 5,
    price: "65",
    weight: "26.9"
  },{
    id: 6,
    price: "120",
    weight: "19.3"
  },{
    id: 7,
    price: "20",
    weight: "45.7"
  }]
```

Now I want to filter the above array of objects based on a range for two parameters `price` and `weight`.

```
let range = {
    startPrice: 15,
    endPrice: 60,
    startWeight: 22.0,
    endWeight: 70.5,
  }
```

I want to filter my list with these range parameters which will return me an array with a subset of objects satisfying both the filter ranges. Hence, the output array should be:

```
filtered = [{
    id: 3,
    price: "45",
    weight: "65.7"
  },{
    id: 7,
    price: "20",
    weight: "45.7"
  }]
```

Because items with `id: 3` and `id: 5` satisfy the subset of both of the two ranges. How should my `list.filter()` function look like? Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What do you think it should look like? Filter takes a function and should return true/false.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, well but how do you return the subset? I'm comparing from a subset of two params.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. The output of filter returns a subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I've used `parseFloat` because values are stored as a `String`.  There are other ways to get a `Number` out of a `String`.

```js
var list = [{"id":1,"price":"10","weight":"19.45"},{"id":2,"price":"14","weight":"27.8"},{"id":3,"price":"45","weight":"65.7"},{"id":4,"price":"37","weight":"120.5"},{"id":5,"price":"65","weight":"26.9"},{"id":6,"price":"120","weight":"19.3"},{"id":7,"price":"20","weight":"45.7"}];
var range = {
  startPrice: 15,
  endPrice: 60,
  startWeight: 22.0,
  endWeight: 70.5
};

var filtered=list.filter(
  element=> {
    var elementprice=parseFloat(element.price);
    var elementweight=parseFloat(element.weight);
    if(
      elementprice>=range.startPrice &&
      elementprice<=range.endPrice &&
      elementweight>=range.startWeight &&
      elementweight<=range.endWeight
    ) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
);
console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Filter is much simpler than a reduce

Comment: @mplungjan, do you know what is more efficient:
`filter(item=>(condition1 && condition2 && condition3 && condition4))`, or
`filter(item=>condition1).filter(item=>condition2).filter(item=>condition3).filter(item=>condition4)`?
Say, huge arrays vs tiny, memory, speed, other things that I didn't think of yet?

Comment: It does not matter for a few hundred items, but why change to filter? Now your code is the same as mine. It was just a comment

Comment: Also no need to use an if when a filter uses a boolean See my answer for the simplest implementation

Answer (score 1):

You mean 3 and 7

Also you need to either remove the quotes or cast to number. Note a filter will expect a true or false to a Boolean test is enough. No if or else needed

```js
const list = [{ id: 1, price: "10", weight: "19.45" }, { id: 2, price: "14", weight: "27.8" }, { id: 3, price: "45", weight: "65.7" }, { id: 4, price: "37", weight: "120.5" }, { id: 5, price: "65", weight: "26.9" }, { id: 6, price: "120", weight: "19.3" }, { id: 7, price: "20", weight: "45.7" }];
 let range = { startPrice: 15, endPrice: 60, startWeight: 22.0, endWeight: 70.5, }

const res = list.filter(item => 
  +item.price >= range.startPrice && 
  +item.price <= range.endPrice &&
  +item.weight >= range.startWeight &&  
  +item.weight <= range.endWeight);
console.log(res);
```